# How to Filter overlaid Exchange calendar in Sharepoint Calendar 2013

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, exchange

I was successful to overlay the exchange calendar into SharePoint calendar. But is there an option on what I can display in SharePoint site, for instance I want to display title and body of an appointment in the SharePoint calendar. Also can I make changes on exchange events from SharePoint site?

Answer (score 0):

y default, the calendar will only show limited (free/busy) information about the event for the logged on user. This setting is controlled by the permission level in the outlook calendar. You can change this from "Outlook | File | Options | Calendar | Free/Busy options" under "Calendar Options". The permission level is set to "free/busy time" by default. If you wish to show more details in the Exchange calendar in SharePoint, you can change the permission level to "Full Details".

Check the Step 4 [in this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/anand_nigam/archive/2011/05/18/the-one-with-sharepoint-and-exchange-calendar-together.aspx) for permission issue.

For second part, i dont thing you can update the Exchange calerndar from SharePoint, i never tried it.

Their is 3rd party web part available for this [Virto Sharepoint Calendar - Exchange Edition](http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/exchange-group-calendar-web-part)

Comment: Thank you for your response Waqas, I have seeing rather weird behavior in my exchange overlay. I created a exchange mailbox calendar for a team and want to overlay that in the SharePoint calendar. But it keeps on displaying my outlook calendar in the SharePoint calendar, even after explicitly specifying other mailbox. How to display the different mailbox contents?